# Sequelize error when trying to connect to it using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, backend

ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:5432 error when running docker compose up for my docker to start my backend

Postgres(node_db) is up and running but it fails to compile the backend (customerportal).
Tried different things but nothing worked.
Any idea why?

**database**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.PGDATABASE,
  process.env.PGUSER,
  process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.PGHOST,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  }
)

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:14

EXPOSE 3001

WORKDIR /src

RUN npm install i npm@latest -g

COPY package.json package-lock*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "app/index.js"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
services:
  node_backend:
    container_name: customerportal
    image: customerportal:0.0.4
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - EXTERNAL_PORT=3001
      - PGDATABASE=customerportal_db
      - PGUSER=filip
      - PGPASSWORD=12345
      - PGHOST=node_db
    depends_on:
      - node_db
  node_db:
    container_name: node_db
    image: "postgres:15"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=filip
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345
      - POSTGRES_DB=customerportal_db
    volumes:
      - nps_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  nps_data: {}
```